# std::string c_str() scope after returning from function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, object-lifetime

I have below mentioned function in C++/MFC:

```
CString StringFunc()
{
    std::string abc = "Hello";

    return abc.c_str();

}

int main()
{
    CString Temp = StringFunc();

    Use_Temp(Temp);
}
```

1.) What would be the lifetime of abc.c_str() pointer returned by StringFunc(), would it be safely copied to variable 'Temp' after StringFunc() returns ?

2.) CString Temp = StringFunc() is a Shallow copy operation or Deep Copying ?

Comment: Your code was not indented at all, and you used `void main`. I edited the question to fix those problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be the lifetime of abc.c_str() pointer returned by StringFunc(), would it be safely copied to variable 'Temp' after StringFunc() returns ?

`abc` will be valid until `StringFunc() function` returns. Yes, it's safe to return a copy to CString.

If you return a pointer to `std::string::c_str()` then it's dangerous, for example:

```
const char* EvilFunc()  // bad, dont' do it
{
   std::string abc = "Hello";
   return abc.c_str();
}

const char* p = EvilFunc(); // p becomes wild pointer when EvilFunc returns
```

---

> CString Temp = StringFunc() is a Shallow copy operation or Deep Copying ?

It's deep copy. it constructs a new `CString` object from `const char*`

Comment: How do you make EvilFunc a good one?. I have the same scenario an coverity tool is reporting some issue at the return of c_str().

Answer (score 2):

Ad.1) - You are not returning a char pointer, you are returning an instance of `CString` implicitly constructed from that pointer. `CString` takes a copy of passed character data.

Ad.2) - Copying or assigning a `CString` creates a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

1.): The lifetime of the `char const *` returned by `c_str()` is only as long as the control flow is inside the function `StringFunc`, since the string variable `abc` will be destroyed at the end of that function. However, since you return a CString by value, a temporary is implicitly constructed from the result of `c_str()`, and that CString is returned; this temporary return value in turn is valid until the end of the expression that the function call appears in (i.e. the whole statement where you assign the result of function `StringFunc` to temp). The result from your `StringFunc` is therefore safely copied into your `Temp` variable in `main`.

2.) It's a "deep" copy, you construct a new object there! Since you return by value, your compiler will by most probability actually avoid copying anything (see [Return-Value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)) and will instead simply construct the one object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the memory is safely copied into the `Cstring` object returned from the function. It is a deep copy. [Even the documentation says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> Because the constructors **copy the input data into new allocated
>   storage**, you should be aware that memory exceptions may result.