# LPCWSTR corruption if const char* returned from a function

Tags: c++

I'm experiencing a very strange issue.

I'm looking to output a simple string using MessageBox (expands to MessageBoxW) on Windows.

Here are the methods I'm using:

```
void MainWindow::ShowMessageBox( const std::wstring& title,const std::wstring& message ) const
{
    MessageBox( hWnd,message.c_str(),title.c_str(),MB_OK );
}

std::wstring ConversionHelpers::s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;

    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);

    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);

    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

void DebugHelpers::MsgBox(MainWindow& window, const char* title, const char* message)
{
    std::string t(title);
    std::string m(message);

    window.ShowMessageBox(ConversionHelpers::s2ws(t), ConversionHelpers::s2ws(m));
}
```

This works:

```
MsgBox(wnd, "Test", std::string("Hello").c_str());
```

This doesn't work:

```
const char* get_hello()
{
    return std::string("Hello").c_str();
}

MsgBox(wnd, "Test", get_hello());
```

By 'doesn't work', I mean I'm getting a ton of weird characters.

I know the conversion isn't necessary in this example but in my implementation, it is necessary. That doesn't answer the question about the strangeness though.

I'm doing the exact same thing with both, but one uses a method to return the value rather than accessing it directly.

Comment: The string literal is transformed to wstring, try putting an L in front of it, L"test"

Comment: The `w` in `std::wstring` stands for `wchar_t` and wide characters. They are different from narrow characters using `char`.

Comment: @chris: You're correct.

Comment: Made a slight mistake, updating question

Comment: @RickyFisher Debug those conversion functions.  That is where the bulk of the work is done.

Comment: Related question, for a similar yet safer situation: [std::string c_str() scope after returning from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244331/stdstring-c-str-scope-after-returning-from-function). The key difference is the return type of the function. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244472/9837301) brings up returning a `const char *` as dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::string` that `get_hello()` creates is freed when it goes out of scope upon exit, leaving the returned `char*` pointing at invalid memory before you can even use it.

It would be better to make `get_hello()` return the `std::string` instead, and then the caller can call `c_str()` on the returned `std::string` add needed:

```cpp
std::string get_hello()
{
    return std::string("Hello");
}

MsgBox(wnd, "Test", get_hello().c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str` points to memory owned by the `std::string` object.  When the associated `std::string` object is destroyed, that memory is freed.  Any further attempt to access it results in undefined behavior.

Anonymous temporary objects (such as the `std::string` object created with `std::string("Hello").c_str()`) live until the end of the full expression in which they were created.  That essentially means they go out of scope at the next semicolon.

When you call `MsgBox(wnd, "Test", std::string("Hello").c_str());`, the temporary `std::string` survives until the end of the `MsgBox` function call.  By the time it goes out of scope `MsgBox` is done using it, and nothing else attempts to access the memory pointed to by the pointer returned by `c_str`.  Everything is fine.

In you second case, you create a temporary `std::string` object again.  This time it only survives until the end of the `return` statement in `get_hello`.  By the time control returns to the calling function the temporary `std::string` created in `get_hello` is gone, and the pointer you returned is left dangling, pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: Should I use memcpy or something similar to get a copy of the const char* instead of using the one produced by the now-deleted value pointed to by c_str()?

Comment: You should just return the `std::string` object and let it manage the memory, as @RemyLebeau shows in their answer.  You could allocate your own memory, but doing so will be more complicated, more error prone, and probably less efficient.